# Get combobox value python

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I have looked on the internet but I can't move forward. Here it is, I have a combobox with a list of files' name that I display in the combobox. Once selected in the combobox, I would like to get the selected value. The function valeurList works, I have tried with other values. I have also tried with textvariable inside ttk.Combobox but without success. It returns something but it is blanck...Here is my code :

```
from tarfile import PAX_FIELDS
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import CENTER, ttk
from turtle import bgcolor, width
from dataAcquire import listAcquire
from dataMeasure import Acquisitions
import dataAcquire
import dataMeasure
from numpy import pad, size

dataAcquire.listAcquire()
sensorList=["Température", "CO2", "CO", "Humidité", "Bruit", "Vibrations"]

def valeurList():
    dataAcquire.recupName(current_value)

#create window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("HarshSensor - Calcul de vos points de pénibilité")
root.geometry("950x600")
root.iconphoto(False, tk.PhotoImage(file='./image/icone.png'))

#create 2 frames
frame1 = tk.Frame(root, pady=30)
frame1.pack()
frame2 = tk.Frame(root)
frame2.pack()

#Label date et heure et boutton refresh
labelDH = tk.Label(frame1, text="Choisissez l'acquisition : ", padx=30)
labelDH.pack(side="left")

liste = ttk.Combobox(frame1, values=Acquisitions.listAcquisitions, state="readonly")
liste.pack(side="left", padx=20)
current_value=liste.get()

refresh = tk.Button(frame1, text="Refresh", command=valeurList)
refresh.pack(side="left")
```

Comment: You're calling `liste.get()` about a millisecond after creating the widget. The user won't have even seen it, much less be able to select something from it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This example should grab your value, store it in the variable current_value and then print the value when you call valuerList from the button click.

```
from tarfile import PAX_FIELDS
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import CENTER, ttk
from turtle import bgcolor, width
from dataAcquire import listAcquire
from dataMeasure import Acquisitions
import dataAcquire
import dataMeasure
from numpy import pad, size

dataAcquire.listAcquire()
sensorList=["Température", "CO2", "CO", "Humidité", "Bruit", "Vibrations"]

def valeurList():
    current_value = liste.get() #this will get the information from the combobox
    liste.delete("0", tk.END) # this will clear the field after button click
    dataAcquire.recupName(current_value)
    print(current_value)

#create window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("HarshSensor - Calcul de vos points de pénibilité")
root.geometry("950x600")
root.iconphoto(False, tk.PhotoImage(file='./image/icone.png'))

#create 2 frames
frame1 = tk.Frame(root, pady=30)
frame1.pack()
frame2 = tk.Frame(root)
frame2.pack()

#Label date et heure et boutton refresh
labelDH = tk.Label(frame1, text="Choisissez l'acquisition : ", padx=30)
labelDH.pack(side="left")


liste = ttk.Combobox(frame1, values=Acquisitions.listAcquisitions,
                     textvariable=tk.StringVar(), state="readonly")
liste.pack(side="left", padx=20)


refresh = tk.Button(frame1, text="Refresh", command=valeurList)
refresh.pack(side="left")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `textvariable` attribute of type `tk.StringVar` to `Combobox` constructor and this variable will get updated whenever you change selection in combobox.

Comment: You don't have to assign a textvariable to the combobox. You can, but it's not necessary.